# Multilevel (lmer) problems when using weights

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, convergence

I'm having some troubles when running my multilevel model. Specifically, I'm just fitting a starting simple multilevel model with time (2 years, level 1) nested in individuals (level 2).

Here a sample of data I'm currently using:

```
    structure(list(log_wage = structure(c(7.60090255737305, 7.86326694488525, 
    8.00636768341064, 7.17011976242065, 7.37775897979736, 7.09007692337036, 
    7.42356824874878, 7.37775897979736, 6.91274261474609, 7.58222913742065, 
    7.36073970794678, NA, 7.67322301864624, 7.35436248779297, 8.34284019470215, 
    8.06274795532227, 8.0709056854248, 6.90775537490845, 7.69621276855469, 
    NA, 7.37775897979736, 7.49554204940796, 7.49554204940796, 5.99146461486816, 
    7.64587593078613, 7.78322410583496, NA, 7.67878913879395, 7.21817684173584, 
    7.31322050094604, 7.46737098693848, 7.78322410583496, 7.17011976242065, 
    7.31322050094604, 7.60090255737305, 7.43838357925415, 7.49554204940796, 
    7.31322050094604, 7.43838357925415, 8.00636768341064, 7.78322410583496, 
    7.60090255737305, 7.24422740936279, 8.16051864624023, 7.7406644821167, 
    7.69621276855469, 8.0709056854248, 7.90100717544556, 7.23056316375732, 
    8.29404926300049), format.stata = "%9.0g"), gender = structure(c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = "RECODE of sex", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Female = 0, 
Male = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), outsourced = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    outfirm1 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    outworker = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), ptime = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Part-Time", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    contract_type = structure(c(4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 
    1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
    1, 4), format.stata = "%23.0g", labels = c(Permanent = 1, 
    `Temporary Agency work` = 2, `Apprenticeship contract` = 3, 
    `Other temporary` = 4, `No contract` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), education = structure(c(3, 5, 2, 
    2, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 
    6, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6, 2, 5), format.stata = "%40.0g", labels = c(`Aucun diplôme` = 1, 
    `CEP Brevet des collèges, BEPC, CAP, BEP` = 2, `Bac tech ou profes. ou dipl.de ce niveau` = 3, 
    `Bac général brevet supérieur` = 4, `Bac+2` = 5, `Bac+3 ou Bac+4` = 6, 
    `Dip. supérieur à bac+4` = 7), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), id = structure(c(10000010100001, 
    10000031100001, 10000031100003, 10000040100003, 10000050100002, 
    10000060100002, 10000060100002, 10000081100001, 10000081100002, 
    10000090100001, 10000090100002, 10000111100001, 10000120100001, 
    10000160100001, 10000170100001, 10000170100002, 10000170100002, 
    10000171100002, 10000180100001, 10000180100001, 10000180100002, 
    10000180100002, 10000181100001, 10000190100002, 10000200100002, 
    10000200100002, 10000210100002, 10000220100002, 10000221100002, 
    10000221100003, 10000230100001, 10000240100001, 10000251100001, 
    10000261100002, 10000280100001, 10000290100001, 10000290100001, 
    10000290100002, 10000290100002, 10000291100002, 10000321100001, 
    10000321100002, 10000341100001, 10000341100002, 10000350100001, 
    10000350100001, 10000351100001, 10000351100002, 10000360100001, 
    10000361100002), format.stata = "%14.0f"), year = structure(c(2013, 
    2016, 2016, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2013, 
    2016, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2016, 2013, 
    2016, 2016, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2016, 2013, 
    2013, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2013, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2016), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    coeff_panel = structure(c(281.136444091797, NA, NA, 55.5110130310059, 
    152.79167175293, 107.835258483887, 107.835258483887, NA, 
    NA, 92.9323577880859, 101.953834533691, NA, 60.2477035522461, 
    125.072998046875, 99.6601715087891, 82.2529067993164, 82.2529067993164, 
    NA, 117.65242767334, 117.65242767334, 129.11100769043, 129.11100769043, 
    NA, 75.8703994750977, 87.6044387817383, 87.6044387817383, 
    159.951324462891, 97.5378189086914, NA, NA, 90.5791931152344, 
    149.783706665039, NA, NA, 163.746475219727, 71.2403259277344, 
    71.2403259277344, 103.505813598633, 103.505813598633, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 103.700386047363, 103.700386047363, NA, NA, 
    123.172271728516, NA), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To this data, I'm just fitting the following:

```
no_weight <- lmer(log_wage ~  as.factor(gender) + outsourced + outfirm1 + outworker1 + ptime + as.factor(contract_type) + as.factor(education) + (1 | id), data = trial, REML = F)  

weight <- second <- lmer(log_wage ~  as.factor(gender) + outsourced + outfirm1 + outworker1 + ptime + as.factor(contract_type) + as.factor(education) + (1 | id), data = try, REML = F, weights=coeff_panel)
```

The first model runs without any concern, but the second is nearly unidentifiable, even when trying with bobyka optimizer. Does anyone have any idea of why applying weights create such problems to the model?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- quite a lot of observations seem to have missing weights, which will reduce the amount of information and possibly make the model (nearly) unidentifiable
- the model assumption that the weights are inversely proportional to residual variance might be a poor fit

Comment: Yes, I was suspicious about the weights as well. Many thanks for the answer and the two possible sources of problem.